# I want to stamp every single print, how can I do that?

Tags: printing, printer, print-drivers

Is there any universal solution which one stamps/adds watermark automatically on every printed page on any printer and document type?

Comment: No;  **ALL** printing support is handled by each indivdual software itself.  This would only be possible if the printer itself supported this feature which is unlikely.

Comment: Pre-printed stationery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example [FinePrint](http://fineprint.com/fp/) software (windows only). It is a virtual printer which [allows you to add watermarks](http://fineprint.com/pdftutorial/using-stamps/) and print output to any printer. Other virtual printer software (ex. [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/Pro.asp)) also have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial solution for Windows: [**Print&Share**](http://www.printandshare.info). It allows you to add watermarks to one or more pages. Not only watermarks but also images, overlays, and more can be added. It allows you to add one or more printers, even batch-printing (adding 50+ printers). Besides this also email, pdf, and more is supported.

It can even handle complex page selections via formulas in case you have complex requests to stamp.
This example select all pages except the last 3 pages and checks if the total number of pages is larger than 3 or not:

```
1 - Parse(IfElse(LastPage() <= 3; LastPage(); LastPage() - 3))
```